# How do I install the Macbuntu theme on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, macbuntu

I have downloaded Macbuntu, extracted it inside the downloads folder, and opened the terminal, I don't know how to edit or anything.

How do I install the Macbuntu theme on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: It 'll help you a lot to read the [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) help wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in terminal (on the extracted folder of Macbuntu) run `./install.sh`

Then you'll be able to select what to install / tweak.

You should see a screen like this:
[image]

More info [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-osx-in.html).